# Exception opening a second Activity using an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick, onclicklistener, buttonclick

this is my start activity:

```
Button bfour;
Button bsix;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    bfour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonfour);
    bfour.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, cfour.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    bsix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsix);
    bsix.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, csix.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

When I click on the Buttons my app crashes. And if I write just `this` instead of `StartActivity.this` then it won't compile.

Comment: ´post your messages displayed in logCat! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok, but the Activities `cfour.class` and `csix.class` must extend `Activity` and must be defined into your `AndroidManifest.xml`, something like:

```
<activity
        android:name=".cfour"/>    
<activity
        android:name=".csix"/>
```

Comment: thank you sooooo much !!! i didnt know that when i add new java-classes they are not automatically defined in my manifest

Comment: @FatmaErtugrul when you add a Java class it wont be added in manifest. When you add an `Activity` then the class is added to the manifest.